# How to retrieve app's popular tags? (Quickblox iOS SDK)

Tags: quickblox

There is a very useful function in quickblox admin dashboard — popular tags.

I am wondering if I can get all these tags (tags, not users) with some kind of request? (I am using quickblox iOS SDK). I need them to build a suggestion list for a user. I really hope there is an alternative solution rather than handling it with Custom Objects (way too much work for this).

Answer (score 0):

iOS SDK don't contain API for direct retrieving of popular tags. You can hardcode all your tags or get tags from user, and  then retrieve users by selected tag by means of method

**usersWithTags:delegate:**
 (http://sdk.quickblox.com/ios/Classes/QBUsers.html)

May be in future this option will be added to SDK.